# jquery inserts in div

Tags: jquery

i am having problem with jquery inserts i am using bbedit to inserts images links bold italic etc in my message box and jquery inserts the required html in the corresponding form but its not doing correctly. in below code

in the below code .bbedit-toolbar and .bbedit-smileybar is getting inserted by jquery automatically but in my code its not getting inserted .here is the link for the complete bbcode example http://www.w3theme.com/jquery-bbedit/

any help will be highly appreciated.

```
$("#form_message").bind("change keyup", function() {
    $("#form_submit").removeAttr("disabled");
    $("#form_submit").addClass("att_submit_active");
});
$("#form_message").keyup(function() {
    if ($("#attachment").val() == "status") {
        var max = parseInt($("#form_message").attr("maxlength"));
        if ($(this).val().length > max) {
            $(this).val($(this).val().substr(0, $(this).attr("maxlength")));
        }
        $("#charsRemaining").html("You have <strong>" + (max - $(this).val().length) + "</strong> characters remaining");
    }
})
```

Comment: Format your code please.

Comment: What what I see your syntax is messed up, it won't run.

Comment: You may want to improve your 0% accept rating.

Comment: @tfbox sir i am trying from past several days and just found that jquery is not inserting required html in form so its not displaying here is the link from where i have got the  bbedit code http://www.w3theme.com/jquery-bbedit/

Comment: @tfbox sir here is the code where its perfectly working you can check that jquery inserts bbcode javascript automatically wherever required just we have to add .js script and call the function at top but in my script that bbedit is not getting added any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: @tfbox   $("#stream_att_blogs_radio").click(function() {
       $("#form_message").hide();
       $(".bbedit-toolbar").hide();
       $(".bbedit-smileybar").hide();
       $("span#spanstatus").html("<img src=\"http://www.smaboy.com/files/loading.gif\" /> Loading");
       $("#apps_box").load("http://www.smaboy.com/blogs/ajax_form/u/28373", function() {
        $("span#spanstatus").html("");
        $("#form_submit").removeAttr("disabled");
        $("#form_submit").addClass("att_submit_active");
       });
       
       
      });

Comment: @sujit-tiwari: please edit the original JS code in your question because the ``keyup`` and the first ``if`` don't have a matching close bracket.

Comment: @marcosfromero sir that code is just example as i was not able to post all codes so i have given in my js code everything is exactly same as the one which is working at other site i dont know what mistake i am fdoing

Comment: @marco i am not able to add this line in my pages $(".bbedit-toolbar").css("display","block");
    $(".bbedit-smileybar").css("display","block");
it should be automatically added by jquery

Comment: @marco now its ok $("#form_message").bind("change keyup",function() {
     $("#form_submit").removeAttr("disabled");
     $("#form_submit").addClass("att_submit_active");
    });

    $("#form_message").keyup(function() {
     if ($("#attachment").val() == "status") {
      var max = parseInt($("#form_message").attr("maxlength"));
      if($(this).val().length > max){
       $(this).val($(this).val().substr(0, $(this).attr("maxlength")));
      }
      $("#charsRemaining").html("You have <strong>" + (max - $(this).val().length) + "</strong> characters remaining");
     }
    });

Comment: still the code is not working